# Performance difference with same mysql Select on different server

Tags: mysql, performance-testing, explain

The view of an Drupal-Installation creates a select with subselect.
On mysql from hoster (5.5) there is a performance problem.
On my local mysql installation (5.6) the select took only few seconds.

I tried explain on both servers with exact the same select query.

The difference is only in this row (subselect ):

**Local-Server with good performance:**

```
1   PRIMARY <derived2>  ref <auto_key0> <auto_key0> 5   gartenstaudentest.node_comment_statistics.nid   10  NULL
```

**Hoster-Server with bad performance:**

```
1   PRIMARY <derived2>  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    12473
```

12473 is the count of rows of the subselect.
When I test only the subselect on the local mysql, the result is also 12473.
But the row in Explain is only 10???

I made a dump from the structure of the tables and checked with winmerge.
The keys are the same in both databases.
The count of rows is basically the same.

Any idea, how I can localize the performance problem?

Comment: Not sure, what you mean with "the keys are the same" (key also means index), do you mean the tables have the same data? Cause it looks like the server with the bad performance is simply missing the index you have in your fast server. Please do `show create table your_table_name\G` and post the result.

Comment: Yes, sorry for my bad english...
I mean the PRIMARY Keys and indizes are the same in both databases.

The show create table-Result will comes soon.

Comment: Okay, I will have a look then. It's probably also a good idea to post the whole query, not just the subselect and the whole output of `explain`. I don't know what hardware you're using, but when you really have just 12473 rows in that table, "a few seconds" may also be too much.